# Get the type of element in a selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I find the underlying element of a d3 selection?

I tried `d3.select(elem).node()` gives the entire node, not just the element. I also checked (in v5) that there is a `_groups`, and I could potentially derive the element from there. But is there a more direct method?

**Edit**

For e.g.

```javascript
var svg = d3.select('svg');
renderChart(svg);

...

var g = d3.select('g');
renderChart(g);


function renderChart(element){
  // I want to find out here if the element (selection) passed
  // is "svg" or a "g", and then take appropriate action

  // element.node() is giving me the whole object -- not just that particular element

  if (<tbd> == "svg"){
     // take action here
  }
}
```

`element.node()` in the above example returns an object. For e.g. in case of `svg`, it looks like this in Chrome console

[image]

In my real case, I have the main chart that I have to draw on SVG element, but I need to provide clickable actions on that chart, which will run the same chart code, but with different data to generate a "sub chart" and append it as "g" element.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to determine the type of a DOM element:

1. For any type of node you can always get the name of the node by reading [`Node.nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName). In your example:

   ```
   element.node().nodeName === "svg"
   ```
2. If you know that your node is an element type you can refer to the specific interface's property [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName):

   ```
   element.node().tagName === "svg"
   ```
3. You can make use of the well-known symbol [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) to access the element's interface name:

   ```
   element.node()[Symbol.toStringTag] === "SVGSVGElement"
   ```
4. The most typesafe way will be to directly compare the element's constructor to the DOM interface:

   ```
   element.node().constructor === SVGSVGElement
   ```

Here is the executable demo for all the above approaches:

```js
const element = d3.select("svg");

console.log(element.node().nodeName === "svg");
console.log(element.node().tagName === "svg");
console.log(element.node()[Symbol.toStringTag] === "SVGSVGElement");
console.log(element.node().constructor === SVGSVGElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Just fyi, `element.node()[Symbol.toStringTag]` is returning `undefined` in Safari (I have no idea why).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Same here. Second surprise of the day! Sad, but true...